# Connecting to Local Database with Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt

I have a local Database running on localhost:3306, which I access with MySQL Workbench. This works fine, I can create alter, do whatever I want to table. I have two Schemas, "test" and "test2".

I want to connect to it via Qt. here is my code:

```
QSqlDatabase m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL"); 
m_db.setHostName("localhost");
m_db.setDatabaseName("test");
m_db.setPort(3306);
m_db.setUserName("root");
m_db.setPassword("MyAwesomePasswordThatIsUnHackableAndNotMyBirthdayAtAll...");
bool ok = m_db.open();
```

I followed the example found here [QSqlDataBase Class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html)

and m_db.open() always returns false. I'm not too sure what I have to pass to addDataBase() or setDataBaseName. Thanks for the help!

Edit: If I use addDatabase("QMYSQL") the error is "Driver not loaded"
I'm on windows 7, using Qt 4.8.1.

Comment: There is a method QSqlDatabase::lastError(). What does that return?

Comment: Which database do you want to use? SQLite (QSQLITE Driver), MySQL (QMYSQL) or Postgresql (QPSQL)?

Comment: Well I'm running a MySQL instance, so I would like to use that, but if I use the "QMYSQL" driver, it says driver not found.

Comment: You can use only the QMYSQL driver to connect to a mysql database. What pperating system & version are you running, how did you install Qt? EDIT: What's in QSqlDatabase::drivers()?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, using Qt 4.8.1. I installed it using their in my include\QtSQL I can see QMYSQLDRIVER andqsql_mysql.h

Comment: There is no MySQL precompiled plugin installed. You have to compile it yourself. Or you may also use ODBC gateway to your MySQL database, since QODBC plugin is installed or can be easily compiled (without a need of MySQL development libraries).

Comment: @Archile can you write this as an answer so I can accept it? thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no MySQL precompiled plugin installed. You have to compile it yourself. Or you may also use ODBC gateway to your MySQL database, since QODBC plugin is installed or can be easily compiled (without a need of MySQL development libraries).